# Conditionally formatting if Top 10 in two categories?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have two columns of data. I want to find which cities are in the top 10 in both columns (format  IF in `top10_1` AND `top10_2`), and this is the formula I am trying to use:

```
=AND(LARGE($B$2:$B$330,10),(LARGE($C$2:$C$330,10))
```

Any suggestions on what I can do to make it work? I included some sample data if it helps.

```
CityState       Climate     Housing
Stamford, CT    2.959       -4.234
Norwalk, CT     2.959       -4.118
San Diego, CA   2.955       -4.160
Honolulu, HI    2.949       -4.146
San Jose, CA    2.946       -4.205
```

Answer (score 1):

`LARGE` returns the nth highest value in a set, so your condition would be something like:

```
=AND($B2 >= LARGE($B$2:$B$330,10),$C2 >= LARGE($C$2:$C$330,10))
```

Note the relative row reference in each condition so that the conditional formatting applies to each row individually.